# Capturing onClick in a React Router Link

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

Customary "I am new to React, Redux, and ES6"...

I need to notify my Component, or more specifically call a Action (or similar, I need to update an object in the store) whenever a user clicks on a redux-router Link. For example:

```
render(){
        return (
           <Link to={'/leaf/' + node.Id}>
                <div className="col-md-2" style={divStyle}>
                    <label>
                        {node.Title}
                    </label>
                </div>
            </Link>
        );
      }
```

I want to be notified when the user clicks the Link. I don't want to stop anything from happening, I just want to fire off an async call back to the store so a variable gets updated.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can probably attach an `onClick={// some function}` prop to the Link element. If that doesn't work, you can add it to the label html element.

It shouldn't stop anything from propagating unless you specifically tell it to.